# Word for ditching someone in a taxi

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

Is there a word for this sort of situation:

Jack and Jill meet for the first time, and eventually agree to return home together for "coffee". They take a taxi to Jacks house, but as they pull up and he gets out She tells the driver to take her on to her own way instead. Jack is left confused...

Nowadays we have words like *ghosting*, Is there anything that exists to describe this?

*Gutted Jack, she really Blerblered you there!*

Comment: How about "changed her mind"?

Comment: nothing wrong with ... 'ditching' Jack.